# Div Design - Attempting To Create Info Box, Hover Opening Independent/Original Box

Tags: html, class

I'm attempting to design a hover/drop down box on vBulletin to reveal a member's additional statistics when hovered, however my current code has it so that only the box of the original post (or the first div box) on the page is being opened. What am I doing wrong here?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMySJ.png

Code:

```html
<center>
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById('div_name').style.display='';" 
onmouseout="document.getElementById('div_name').style.display='none';" 
href="" onclick="return false;" 
style="text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
padding-left: 31px;
padding-right: 31px;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background-color: #efefef;
border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
border-left: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-top: 4px;">
<b>Member Information</b></a>

<br />

<div id="div_name" style="display:none;
margin:5px 5px 0px 5px;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #aaa;
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
right: 5px;">

More Information Coming<br>
More Information Coming<br>
More Information Coming<br>

</div>
</center>
```

Comment: is `<div id="div_name"` the real id **div_name** or you just type a name for your question? cause each `div` should have a unique `id` in your page. if not, only the first `div` will be opened. so you can create different ids adding for example the post number to the end of you id and they will be something like this: `<div id="div_name1"`, `<div id="div_name2"`

Comment: You should give them different ID's

Comment: Well the problem is that specific div is responsible for every block on that page. Unfortunately, I'm extremely new when it comes to this. If I assign the div a number, won't the same issue occur as I'm not technically creating new divs?